# Multiple column using select with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I'm looking for a solution to pick up a date on mobile app (using Ionic framework). I would like the user click on a button and it triggers a selection of days, month, year, like on the picture below :

[image]

I'm not talking about multiple selections, but a combination a choice in the same select tag.

Any idea how to do it with JS/AngularJS ? I don't want to use JQuery.

Comment: What do you get on mobile if you set the input type to date?

Comment: javascript datepicker plugin will be better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. It has a list of all the input types and their behavior on mobile devices.

http://mobileinputtypes.com/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Doesn't work with ionic application (neither 'datetime' or 'date', but the website is really helpful)

Comment: Have you come across this link while searching? Might be helpful. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/date-picker-for-ionic/344

Comment: Very useful too, I'll try a solution from this page to compare behavior between native and hybrid component

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution for date. On the ionic website, there is a component which give the opportunity this behavior with date (http://ionicframework.com/html5-input-types/#date).

But I have still no idea how to deal with custom options using multiple columns.